# Calculate field based on values in other field

Tags: excel, row, arcpy, calculated-field

I am trying to think through the logic of this situation so I can form a code that uses the row, next and calculate field functions.

I have several rows with Oil Rig data:
ex.

```
Rig 234
Rig 234
Rig 234
Rig 333
Rig 333
Rig 768
```

I need to populate another field that shows one value for Rows that contain the same rigs, but changes to the next consecutive number when the Rig in the row changes. So Rig 234 = 1
Rig 333 = 2 and Rig 768 = 3.

Below is the outcome I need.

```
RIG:      New Field:
Rig 234   1
Rig 234   1
Rig 234   1
Rig 333   2
Rig 333   2
Rig 768   3
```

I have had zero luck on my own, because I haven't touched Python in a while, I've tried doing =IF statements in Excel to no avail as well.
Any help provided would be awesome!

Comment: Is the order of indexes for rigs important to you?
e.g. for your example can Rig 333 -> 1 and Rig 234 -> 2?
If not, could it be ok if rigs are sorted by name and then assigned indexes?

Answer (score 0):

Please seed the process with `1` in your top data row (assumed to be Row2, so in B2) then in the cell below and copied down to suit:

```
=IF(A2=A3,B2,B2+1)
```

Comment: It element A -> 1 is repeated after another element B -> 2 it appears as A -> 3 instead of A -> 1

Answer (score 0):

Here's an example in python. It assumes the rigs are supposed to be in a logical order and shouldn't start with index 0.

```
rigs = ['Rig 234', 'Rig 234', 'Rig 234', 'Rig 333', 'Rig 333', 'Rig 768']
rig_set_list = list(set(rigs))
rig_set_list.sort()

for rig in rigs:
    print("%s %s" % (rig, rig_set_list.index(rig)+1))
```

Which gives the result:

```
Rig 234 1
Rig 234 1
Rig 234 1
Rig 333 2
Rig 333 2
Rig 768 3
```

Comment: I have a feeling that OP wouldn't be comfortable with python.

Comment: Used python example since OP mentioned python in their question and tagged with arcpy.